# moving a Image with mouse cursor in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need to move a image with the mouse cursor in kivy it dosent mean that i want to change the mouse pointer to some image because i would then need to change the angle or that image whenever there will be a touch event .

I found that we have MotionEvent in kivy but then that is working only when we have a touch event with move or press down or up . I need something when we just move cursor without touch ?

Comment: I am sorry but your question sounds a bit unclear. Do you wish to simply retrieve the mouse cursor events?

Comment: I want to move an image with mouse moving without touch or press

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `mouse_pos` variable in the Window class. For example:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.0.8')

from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock
from functools import partial


class MyMouse(App):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyMouse, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_interval(partial(self.my_callback), 0.05)

    def my_callback(self, dt):
        print Window.mouse_pos

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyMouse().run()
```

Comment: I was looking for something like this . Thank You !

Comment: You are welcome. You may need to set the interval of the schedule function depending on your use case. 0.5 may be too slow!

Comment: Oh yeah i have already did that . tested and it works ... Now i am trying to find a mechanism to rotate image .. Just started leaning kivy and its very interesting :)