# Kivy: Hide mouse cursor on desktop

Tags: python, kivy

I have a fullscreen app and I'm trying to hide the mouse cursor. The setup is **Kivy 1.9.0** on **Python 3.4.1** for **Windows**, using the prepared packages.

I have tried the following approaches, with no success:

1- Using [Config](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.config.html) object:

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set("graphics", "show_cursor", 0)
```

2- Editing .kivy\config.ini:

```
[graphics]
.
.
.
show_cursor = 0
```

3- Using pygame:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
```

4- Moving the mouse off-screen:

```
def move_mouse_away(etype, motionevent):
  # this one doesn't get called at all
  Window.mouse_pos = [1400, 1000]

Window.bind(on_motion=move_mouse_away)
```

5- Using [Clock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726503/moving-a-image-with-mouse-cursor-in-kivy) for a similar effect:

```
Clock.schedule_interval(self._reset_mouse, 0.05)

def _reset_mouse(self, time):
  Window.mouse_pos = [1400, 1400]
```

I'm a little out of ideas now.

Comment: using config worked for me

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Window.show_cursor](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html#kivy.core.window.WindowBase.show_cursor)

It was added in kivy version 1.9.1

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.show_cursor = False
```

Answer (score 2):

I just read the documentation, tried it and fixed it (version 1.9.0).  To hide the cursor from the application window permanently (even if you are using a touchscreen) :

```
>>> from kivy.config import Config
>>> Config.set('graphics','show_cursor','0')
>>> Config.write()
>>> quit()
```

I use a touch screen (LG 19MB15T) which works 'out_of_the_box'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same kind of problem: I need to hide or change my mouse cursor in a kivy app.

I don't have a perfect solution only a partial one:

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.core.window import Window
import win32api

class NoCursorWindow(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NoCursorWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        Window.bind(mouse_pos=self.on_mouse_pos)

    def on_mouse_pos(self, *args):
        win32api.SetCursor(None)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from kivy.base import runTouchApp
    runTouchApp(NoCursorWindow())
```

It works only partially:
The problem when you use `win32api.SetCursor()` is that when the mouse moves, the window gets a `WM_SETCURSOR` Message which changes the cursor back to default. This is why the `win32api.SetCursor()` must be triggered for each change of the `mouse_pos`.

But even like that sometimes we can see the default cursor blinking.

If anyone knows how to hook the `WM_SETCURSOR`, to prevent the call back of the default cursor, it could solve this...